# Managing multiple environments with a single target in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, environment

We need to track crashes for all the environments. We have development, Staging, pre-prod and production now.

**Is it possible to set the same bundle id for all environments and track the crashes or do we need to change the different bundle id for the different environment?**

**I followed the link below and created the two bundle id for debug and release. But when I archived, I got a release bundle id only. Do we need to change the archives(development) to debug in edit scheme?**

https://medium.com/@kavithakumarasamy89/xcode-build-settings-user-defined-settings-manage-multiple-environments-with-single-target-3e5c1a307999

Comment: Yeah you need to change your target's scheme so it archives for development as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points you should consider before going to solve the multiple environment issue with the same target.

- You can set same bundle Id for different environment.
- The apps with same bundle Id could not reside in same device.
- So if you want to debug any crash on any iOS device, you should have installed/deployed each build with different bundle Id to generate the scenario.
- The Bundle Id will be different for that target for each build(pointed to different environment).